# Dynamically create variable name

Tags: objective-c, string, variables, dynamic, nsstring

In objective-c is there a way to dynamically create a variable name. Like I pass a string into a method and the method creates an NSString whos name is the string that was passed in. Something like

```
-(void)create:(NSString *)str{

NSString *[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", str];
}
```

Or maybe there is a way to change an already existing variables name.

```
NSString *password;
password.name = entryPassword;
```

Comment: objC is not an interpreted language

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're trying to do…

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  I'd be willing to say that if you think you need to do this, then your approach is totally wrong.

Comment: Isn't answering "no" better than a downvote here? IMO it's not a poorly asked question, just one that's basic.

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure that someone will point out some obscure exception, but in general, this is not possible in any compiled language.

Answer (score 2):

I would look into [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

An NSMutableArray's size can change and all objects are retained in it.

So, you can store locally created strings inside the `NSMutableArray` and access the string later.

So you can have a ivar mutableArray of type `NSMutableArray` and then you can store locally created strings:

```
//In your init method
mutableArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//In your create method:
[mutableArray addObject: [NSString initWithString:str]];
```

This doesn't do exactly what you are saying, but it probably is the closest you are going to get. (Or I am misunderstanding your question).

Comment: I'd say an NSMutableDictionary is closer to what he wants. (But that does not change the fact that he should really rethink what he is trying to do and how he is attempting to do it)

Answer (score 2):

In C# (also compiled language) it's called reflection : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx and as per definition you can "dynamically create an instance of a type, bind the type to an existing object, or get the type from an existing object and invoke its methods or access its fields and properties.".

I don't get why ppl ask "why would one want to do what they want to do" instead of simply answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

I came to this question a few weeks ago and treated the answer with the biggest number of points (by mmc) as a fact, but **in at least 1 context you can dynamically “create” variable name in Objective C**.

My teacher, [Jacek Lampart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967872/jacek-lampart), showed me how and I thought I’ll share it with other newbies.

The meat:

```
// Sample for loop

for(int i=1; i<=3; i++)
{
    // Here you define the format of variable.
    // In this example it’s gonna be blablabla1, blablabla2, blablabla3.

    NSString *targetVariableName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"blablabla%d", i];

    // Sample UIImageView variable.
    // You assign self.blablabla1 (self.blablabla2 and so on) 
    // to currentVariable in a way, which enables you to work
    // with this object (for example setImage to it etc.).

    UIImageView *currentVariable = [self valueForKey:targetVariableName];

    // […]

    // Profit & DRY power! 
}
```